# $2^{x+3}+3^{x-5}=2^{3x-7}+3^{2x-10}$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

Related to solving $~~2^{x+3}+3^{x-5}=2^{3x-7}+3^{2x-10}$

I've tried some arithmetic to find something like

$a^x=b~\Longrightarrow~x=\log_{a}b$

But what I've found is that

$2^{x+3}+3^{x-5}=2^{3x-7}+3^{2x-10}$

$2^8\cdot2^{x-5}+3^{x-5}=2^8\cdot2^{3(x-5)}+3^{2(x-5)}$

$256\cdot2^{x-5}+3^{x-5}=256\cdot(2^{x-5})^3+(3^{x-5})^2$

$256\cdot a +b=256\cdot a^3+b^2$

$256 \cdot a(a^2-1)+b(b-1)=0$

I don't know how to solve this equation above. Maybe it doesn't the better way to solve my question (tittle) or maybe it is wrong.

Can someone help me to solve that?

Comment: Can you find an $x$ with $x+3 = 3x - 7$ and $x-5 = 2x-10$. If so, you've got a solution because each term on the left matches the corresponding term on the right.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. This question does not meet the standards we look for on this site. Please see "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question , particularly the portion on providing context.  You can edit your post to improve it.

Comment: Ok, @CarlMummert. I will read it

Comment: @CarlMummert Is it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$0=2^{x+3}(2^{2x-10}-1)+3^{x-5}(3^{x-5}-1)=f(x)$$

As $2^{x+3},3^{x-5}>0$ for real $x,$

If $x-5>0$, then $f(x)>0$, and if $x-5<0$, then $f(x)<0$.

Since we wanted $f(x) = 0$, it must be true that $x - 5 \not< 0$ and $x - 5 \not> 0$. So $x - 5 = 0$, and thus $x = 5$.

Comment: Ouch! Beat me by a few seconds! meh...

Comment: I don't see how this helps find $x$.

Comment: @diligar, So, $x\not>5, \not<5$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Then you should conclude your answer with something like "Since $f(x)=0$, $x-5=0$

Comment: @diligar, Since $f(5)=0,x=5$ is the unique solution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you so much, it took me a little time to understand. You've solved my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnHughes hinted at in the comments, the trick to solving $2^{x+3}+3^{x−5}=2^{3x−7}+3^{2x−10}$ is in realizing that powers of two are always even, and powers of three are always odd, so a power of two won't ever affect the value of a power of three. (**Edit:** This is only true when you are multiplying powers of two by powers of three, not adding them, so this is one solution, there might be others.)

So, basically,
$$\begin{align*}
2^{x+3}+3^{x−5}=2^{3x−7}+3^{2x−10}
&\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
2^{x+3} = 2^{3x-7} \\
3^{x-5} = 3^{2x-10}
\end{cases} \\
&\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x+3 = 3x-7 \\
x-5 = 2x-10
\end{cases} \\
&\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
2x = 10 \\
x = 5
\end{cases}\\
&\Rightarrow x=5
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $2^3 + 3^2 = 17 = 2^4 + 3^0$.  But if you reverse all the $\Rightarrow$ directions, you do obtain that $x = 5$ is a solution to the equation. This argument does not show that $5$ is the only solution.

Comment: `a power of two won't ever affect the value of a power of three` Don't know what that's supposed to mean. Consider for example $2^1+3^2=2^3+3^1$.

Comment: @dxiv Oh that's a good point, then I suppose that this is just one solution. I must have been thinking of multiplying powers of two with powers of three. My bad!